# How do you deal with Duplicate File names in Manifest.JSON for a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to implement a Github library within an extension. The file system has multiple files with the same names like "index.js" but when I look to reference these within the Manifest.json I feel like They will just throw errors

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

"name": "log",
"description": "log",
"version": "1.0",

"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "favicon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},

"options_page": "options.html",

"background": {
    "scripts": [ "eventPage.js", "background.js", "Gruntfile.js", "unittests.js", "crypto.js","index.js", "aes.js", "blowfish.js", "cast5.js","des.js","index.js","towfish.js", "index.js","md5.js","ripemd.js","sha.js", "armor.js", "basic.js", "index.js", "key.js", "keyring.js", "packet.js", "Signature.js", ]


},

"content_scripts": [

    {
        "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ],
        "js": [ "Log.js" ]
    }
],

"permissions" : [
    "storage",
    "notifications",
    "contextMenus",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "tabs"
] 
}
```

Can someone help me find documentation on how to handle file systems duplication within the Manifest.json?

Comment: How does the file system have duplicate files? There is no differences in the location/name of the files?

Comment: what makes you think that chrome will magically know the path to each file? add it

Comment: The files have different file paths but I don't know how the syntax would work. like "master\child\index.js" I can't find anything that confirms that syntax like that would be correct. Or where to Put It in the Manifest.json. I would assume under "Background" within "scripts" but I don't know